# Git fails to pull error unrelated histories

Tags: android, git

So I have an android studio project that I'm syncing between my laptop and my computer with git. Every time I push with one and pull with the other when I try to pull I get error refusing to merge unrelated histories

I tried using --allow-unrelated-histories but that causes a ton of merge conflicts.

I need to be able to sync between the two because my computer supports the emulator and my laptop is portable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because your repositories was initialized independly.

You should create the repository only in one location, and clone it to the other.

If the other repository already exists and you have there some change which you don't want to lose, you could do the following:

```
(from location2, commit all uncommitted changes first!)
git fetch location1
git branch save_location2
git reset --hard origin/location1
```

So you switch to the history started at location1, and would not lose your history started at location2, and will be able to look up stuff from there.

There are exceptional cases where you should use `--allow-unrelated-histories`, but I'm sure it is not your case.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. Try this:

```
git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories 

git push origin master
```

Reference:- [Github unrelated histories issue](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.9.0.txt#L58-L68)